# Wrong image url in media library wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, themes, storefront

Here is the sitution:

I am using WordPress 4.6.1 for my website with Storefront theme from WooCommerce. I have images not appearing on any of the pages on my website, but they all appear in the Media Library. I checked to make sure the files are located in the wp-content/upload folder (it is with a permission of 755 and all images are 644). I checked to make sure were no plugin issues (there are none). The permalink struture is postname. I have the WooCommerce plugin for my site for products and services.  The image URL is missing in the Media Library with the name of the image file and extension in black writing with the view URL as simple-page/name of image.

For example, the image payment.jpg.  The correct URL of that image is http://www.gwbs.biz/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/payments.jpg but under the view link, the file reads http://www.gwbs.biz/sample-page/payments/. When you click on the view link, a page is displayed instead of the image.

I am not sure why it's behaving that way. As a result one of my images are displaying on the page. Just the slug name of the image at the location the image. Is there a solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check `img src` tag in `sample-page/payments/` page. I think, It is not correct url.